# Listening for packets directed to my WAN IP?

Tags: php, sockets, udp, packets

Currently I'm experimenting with sockets and UDP packets.

I created a UDP socket and binded it to 127.0.0.1, and when sending a UDP packet to 127.0.0.1, the server successfully received it.

But I want to be able to send UDP packets from external locations to my server and receive them. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on your network topology and may be more of a question for http://serverfault.com.

Assuming your server is behind a NAT device, i.e. a router, you'd need to configure said device to [forward a certain port to your server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding). Any packet reaching the NAT device on the public IP address on that port will be forwarded to the server as if it had been sent to the server directly.

Comment: Port forwarding is fine, but I'm running everything in my virtual box which is on of course, a virtual ethernet port, so when trying to forward my port to my virtual box, I get an error message along the lines of `IP must be a LAN IP`

Comment: @Rob That would have been a nice detail to put in the question. Anyway, then you need to first forward the packet to the computer running the VM, then make that computer forward it to the VM. Please post this question on http://serverfault.com with all the details you can provide, if you need more help.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I forgot that that would make a difference, lol. On my way to SF, thanks